# Logfile seems to be locked by another process

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a log file using the code given below, but it throws

> Process cannot access a file because it is being used by another process

The code is as follows:

```
string logFile = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\LogFile\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + "TaskLogFile.txt";

      StreamWriter LogWriter;
      try
      {
          if (!File.Exists(logFile))
          {
              LogWriter = new StreamWriter(logFile);
              Console.WriteLine("Log File Created...");
          }
          else
          {
              LogWriter = File.AppendText(logFile);
              Console.WriteLine("Log File Appended...");
          }

          if (EX == null)
          {
              LogWriter.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ");
              LogWriter.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
              LogWriter.WriteLine("\nTask Id = {0} , Task Name = {1}, Service Name = {2} ", TaskId, TaskName, ServiceName);
              LogWriter.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
              LogWriter.Close();
          }

          else
          {
              LogWriter.WriteLine("\n Error : {0}, Error Location : {1},Task ID = {2}, Task Name : {3}, Service Name : {4} " + EX.ToString(), EX.StackTrace, TaskId, TaskName, ServiceName);
          }
      }

      catch (Exception ex)
      {

          LogWriter = File.AppendText(logFile);
          LogWriter.WriteLine("\n Error : {0}, Error Location : {1},Task ID = {2}, Task Name : {3}, Service Name : {4} " + ex.ToString(), Environment.StackTrace, TaskId, TaskName, ServiceName);

      }
```

Also, I am calling this method with other async methods.

Comment: The file must already exist and have an exclusive write lock.  Try opening the file with shared write access

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that the log file is probably **locked** by another process, or by the same one if it's async.

That's a typical problem for logfiles and can be solved easily with `FileShare.ReadWrite`

```
File.Open(logFile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite)
```

Comment: I'd also recommend employing 'using' statements. The only place that the stream is disposed of is if EX is null.

Comment: I made the necessary changes as suggested by you, but its not working.

Comment: Please update your code accordingly, then I will take a look.